# NameError: name 'List' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm really unsure why this isn't working. Here is the important part of the code (it's from a leetcode challenge).
The first line throws the NameError.

```py
def totalFruit(self, tree: List[int]) -> int:
    pass
```

If I try importing `List` first I get an error `No module named 'List'`. I'm using Python 3.7.3 from Anaconda.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

To be able to annotate what types your list should accept, you need to use `typing.List`

```
from typing import List
```

So did you import `List`?

**Update**

If you're using Python > 3.9, [see @Adam.Er8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62496306/308204)

Comment: Awesome the ```from typing import List``` seemed to do the trick, had to also fix up other unrelated errors in my code too thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 74):

Since [Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections), you can use built-in collection types (such as `list`) as generic types, instead of importing the corresponding capitalized types from `typing`.
This is thanks to [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/)

So in Python 3.9 or newer, you could actually write:

```py
def totalFruit(self, tree: list[int]) -> int: # Note list instead of List
    pass
```

without having to import anything.

Comment: And let me say, yeah!:)

Comment: to make it backwards compatible: `from __future__ import annotations` (from the documentation)

Comment: Does this work for `def totalFruit() -> list[int]:` also? Or does it only work for the arguments?

Answer (score 12):

To be able to specify a list of str's in a type hint, you can use the `typing` package, and `from typing import List` (capitalized, not to be confused with the built-in `list`)

Answer (score 2):

If we define a list such as `a = [1,2,3]`, then `type(a)` will return `<class 'list'>`, which means it will be created by built-in `list`.

The `List` is useful for annotating return types. For example, a function signature using Python3: `def threeSumClosest(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:` from https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-to-roman/.